# Python image library, Select random pictures from files

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Hi I need some help with something I'm working on, I have this code that gets 2 pictures from 2 different folders and pastes it over each other creating 1 final merged image, what I want though is to merge two randomly selected pictures from the separate directories, thanks

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import random
import numpy as np

img1 = Image.open("/Users/Liam/Pictures/1/dfd.jpg").convert("RGBA")
img2 = Image.open("/Users/Liam/Pictures/2/face.png").convert("RGBA")

img1.paste(img2, (0,0), mask = img2)
img1.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually pretty easy, check my example below

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import random
import numpy as np

basedir1 = "/Users/Liam/Pictures/1/"
basedir2 = "/Users/Liam/Pictures/2/"
first_image_list = os.listdir(basedir1)
second_image_list = os.listdir(basedir2)
img1 = Image.open(os.path.join(basedir1, random.choice(first_image_list))).convert("RGBA")
img2 = Image.open(os.path.join(basedir2, random.choice(second_image_list))).convert("RGBA")

img1.paste(img2, (0,0), mask = img2)
img1.show()
```

Comment: yes i corrected the code, i had to add `Image.open`